# Can a non-primary key columns be referenced from a foreign key?

Tags: sql-server

Here is table one I want to refer DesignationId to other table but it is not working

```
create table Employees
(
    EmployeeID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    EmployeeNumber int not null,
    LocationID int not null,
    EmployeeName varchar(20) not null,
    DesignationID int not null,
    CategoryID int not null,
)
```

Second table is that .. on third row it is showing error

```
create table Designation
(
    DesignationID int primary key ,
    JobTitle varchar(20) not null,

    CONSTRAINT fk_Designation_Employees 
        FOREIGN KEY (DesignationID) 
        REFERENCES Employees (DesignationID),
)
```

Comment: A foreign key in table #2 **must** reference either the **primary key** (and nothing but the *complete* primary key) from table #1, or any NOT NULL column(s) of a unique index. So if you have a column (or set of columns) that is (are) unique, then you can put an unique index on that (those) column(s) and reference that column, too.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating this incorrectly. Try it this way instead:

```
create table Designation
(
    DesignationID int primary key ,
    JobTitle varchar(20) not null,

)

create table Employees
(
    EmployeeID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    EmployeeNumber int not null,
    LocationID int not null,
    EmployeeName varchar(20) not null,
    DesignationID int not null,
    CategoryID int not null,


    CONSTRAINT fk_Employees_Designation 
        FOREIGN KEY (DesignationID) 
        REFERENCES Designation (DesignationID)
)
```

Many employees linked to a designation. One-To-Many relationship.